# Change background color of TTTabItem when using Three20 library

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm using TTTabStrip in my iPhone app, the screenshot is below

http://i377.photobucket.com/albums/oo217/zhustar/tttabbar.png?t=1265213089

I want to change the background color of the TTTabItem selected from blue to green
and change the color of font from white to black.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `TTTabItem` is styled visually takes advantage of the `TTStyleSheet` mechanisms implemented throughout the Three20 library.
I had to do this for my own project, and I found the simplest way was to subclass `TTDefaultStyleSheet` and override the particular methods that relate to styling the tab items and the tab bars.

The basic idea is to subclass `TTDefaultStyleSheet` and override the methods you want to change. I don't remember exactly which methods they are, but they're along the lines of `tabBarItem` and `tabBarTintColor` etc. You can look at the source of `TTDefaultStyleSheet` to see which methods you need, and what their default implementations look like.

Once you've done this, you need to set your stylesheet as the global stylesheet, like this

```
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:myStyleSheetInstance];
```

That should then allow you set your own styles for the tab items etc.

For more info on Three20 and how to use the Style system, look at http://three20.info